# How to list docker swarm nodes with labels

Tags: docker, label, docker-swarm

How can I easy print all available docker swarm nodes with their labels?

Added labels to nodes like
`$ docker node update --label-add type=one my_node_name`
And default listing nodes with `docker node ls` not showing filters.

Additionally I can list label inspecting each node like:

```
$ docker inspect my_node_name | grep type 
"type": "one"
```

---EDIT--

Similar question [How do I filter docker swarm nodes by label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026638/how-do-i-filter-docker-swarm-nodes-by-label) is about filtering my is about listing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I filter docker swarm nodes by label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026638/how-do-i-filter-docker-swarm-nodes-by-label)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can run something like:

```
docker node ls -q | xargs docker node inspect \
  -f '{{ .ID }} [{{ .Description.Hostname }}]: {{ .Spec.Labels }}'
```

You can adjust that to use a range for prettier formatting instead of printing the default map:

```
docker node ls -q | xargs docker node inspect \
  -f '{{ .ID }} [{{ .Description.Hostname }}]: {{ range $k, $v := .Spec.Labels }}{{ $k }}={{ $v }} {{end}}'
```

Feel free to update the formatted output to the fields you need.

Comment: Awesome example! Just one question - is there any way to print hostname with a fixed length (padded with spaces), so all the labels are aligned in all the lines? Googled but didn't find. Something like `fmt.Printf("%-10v", value)` but in a go template

Comment: @Ivan you can do something like `{{ printf "%25s" .Description.Hostname }}`

Comment: @Ivan and BMitch (can only tag 1 of you in this comment): It is worth opening a separate question-with-answer for both your comments about go-templating the hostname output if such a Q&A doesn't yet exist. Others won't find that bit of info buried here in comments...

Answer (score 1):

My answer here is not what the OP had asked for (that has been answered by @BMitch).
Just to add on @BMitch answer I extended the code to provide some additional node information I found useful hoping it may be useful to someone else.

`docker node ls -q | xargs docker node inspect   -f '{{ .ID }} [hostname={{ .Description.Hostname }}, Addr={{ .Status.Addr }}, State={{ .Status.State }}, Role={{ .Spec.Role }}, Availability={{ .Spec.Availability }}]: Arch={{ .Description.Platform.Architecture }}, OS={{ .Description.Platform.OS }}, NanoCPUs={{ .Description.Resources.NanoCPUs }}, MemoryBytes={{ .Description.Resources.MemoryBytes }}, docker_version={{ .Description.Engine.EngineVersion }}, labels={{ range $k, $v := .Spec.Labels }}{{ $k }}={{ $v }} {{end}}'`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell Core version:

```
docker node ls -q | `
  ForEach-Object { `
    docker node inspect $_ --format '{{ json . }}' | `
    ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 99 } | `
  Select-Object { $_.Description.Hostname }, { $_.Spec.Labels }
```